# Sql Server pass variable to nodes function

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml-parsing

After I did some internet research I found out that nodes function for xml processing of Sql Server does not accept a variable as parameter. If I try to use a variable a get the following error:

> *The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal.*

This is what I am trying to do:

```
SET @xPath = REPLACE(@xPath,'|','/')
SET @xPath = '/' + @xPath + '/text()'
SELECT @ParsedHtml = @ParsedHtml + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),Col.query('.')) + ';' FROM @Html.nodes(@xPath)AS T(Col)
```

Is there any hack i can do to make nodes function accept a variable as parameter???

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable in the path like this:

```
SET @xPath = REPLACE(@xPath,'|','/')

set @ParsedHtml = ''
SELECT @ParsedHtml = @ParsedHtml + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),Col.query('.')) + ';' 
FROM @Html.nodes('/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@xPath")]/text()')AS T(Col)
```

I don't think you can do multiple levels in one variable in the path, which it looks like you are trying to do. You'd have to specify each level with a parameter of it's own.  If you need to do a dynamic number of path levels, you might look into using [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631868/long-path-xquery-in-sql-server).